# Remove background color on image inside markdown table

Tags: css, github, markdown

I have the following table in markdown on GitHub and I want to be able to remove the background color on the images inside the second column. They are transparent png's but there is CSS in markdown that adds `background-color: white;` to all images inside the table.

Is there any way to overwrite that style and have images with a transparent background?

```
| Project State  | Icon |
|----------------|:----:|
| In Development |<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0a2rs.png">|
| In Progress    |<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9uuh.png" style="background-color: transparent;">|
| Completed      |<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlvw7.png">|
```

[image]

Comment: Please, post your jsfiddle.

Comment: You can create markdown with jsfiddle?

Comment: This might be specific to whatever platform you are posting on. Using stackedit.io I don't get the white background.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I'm using the online GitHub editor.

Comment: As I understand it, GitHub will strip out any style attributes and/or tags in your Markdown documents. You are stuck with GitHub's default styles with no way to override them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible.

While `img` elements are whitelisted, the filter only allows
[src and longdesc](http://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/blob/c8e7613/lib/html/pipeline/sanitization_filter.rb#L53) attributes, so your `style` attribute will be stripped.

The only workaround would be to switch from a transparent background to one
matching the actual background, in this case `F8F8F8`.

If you wish to add support for `style` attribute, voice your support for the
[open issue](http://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/issues/192) at the html-pipeline repo.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, just add a class to the table or all images if that is all you have like this.

```
img{background-color:transparent}
```

If that doesn't work, then overwrite it(many don't recommend using the Important, but once it does not hurt). So do it like this:

```
img{background-color:transparent!important}
```

I hope this helps. happy coding!

Comment: GitHub strips all CSS attributes from it's pages. Only markdown and basic HTML can be used.

https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/